# Other Programs Installation

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to find out if I can install normal PC programs be run in Ubuntu. Like MPLAB from Microchip. I have not installed Ubuntu yet as I would need to clarify this first.

Comment: what all software you expect to be on ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

[MPLAB IDE](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/) from Microchip it available for linux. MATLAB is also available from software center

Comment: The MATLAB in the software center is `matlab-support` which integrates an existing MATLAB installation with Ubuntu and does not install MATLAB. To install MATLAB in Ubuntu, you need the UNIX version of the Installation DVD.

Comment: yeah it's obvious right because it's a paid software

Answer (score 0):

While some programs have linux ports, sadly the opposite holds true for a good part of the availible software.For your decision wether to install ubuntu or not, it would be good to see if the software that isn't native for linux but is required by you runs with the `WINE` compatibility Layer, which casts function-calls from Windows-software to the corresponding functions in linux.This means, that `WINE` Is NOT an Emulator.The developers have a database in which they collect information on software that is known to work with `WINE` ,and it would propably be smart to look up the software you want to run there.
For your convenience I will just post the link right here: [appdb.winehq.org](https://appdb.winehq.org/)
If you are interested in the topic, your first step will be to visit their homepage.

---

In case you want to install `WINE`, you can get it from the repositories via `apt-get` or directly from [winehq.org/downloads](https://www.winehq.org/download/), which I would recommend seeing as the version from their site is the newest version, while the one in the repositories always is a bit older.Well anyway, I hope this information will help you in your decision, and I also hope that the info will be of use for people with a similiar problem.